# Whats the best solution to use nuxt pwa features together with fcm?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js, workbox

I want to add firebase cloud messaging to my nuxt.js app that uses workbox to integrate pwa features. The problem is that fcm requires a service worker (*firebase-messaging-sw.js*) that handles incoming messages but workbox also uses a service worker (*sw.js*) to provide pwa features.

As one site can only handle one service worker I tried using the workbox service worker (*sw.js*) for firebase:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then((registration) => {
            fcm.useServiceWorker(registration)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
```

and copying the code from *firebase-messaging-sw.js* into *sw.js*:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js');


const config = {
        messagingSenderId: "12345",
    }

    !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : ''



const messaging = firebase.messaging()
```

But every time I build the project with nuxt the *sw.js* file gets overwritten and the code I copied to handle incoming messages is gone.

whats the best solution to use workbox together with fcm?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I made a mistake.

Just keep the '/firebase-messaging-sw.js' file.

It seems that the firebase function reads it.

I'm sorry if you don't get the answer you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not seem to work :/

Comment: i tried both, keeping both swervice workers and including sw.js in firebase-messaging-sw.js which also did not work for me

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Sorry for not being able to help.

I will comment if I understand something again!